# Undefined Reference to p_thread_create, p_thread_join and p_thread_exit

Tags: c, multithreading, gcc, pthreads

I am currently learning about threads in c and I did this program.

However, I have trouble compiling it. I have searched online for different ways to compile but so far none of them worked for me (though it have worked for others), and I'm not sure why...

I am using Ubuntu 13 with Workstation 10.

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node {
    int i;
    int j;
} NODE;

void merge(int i, int j);
void * mergesort(void *x);

int x[] = {7, 12, 19, 3, 18, 4, 2, 6, 15, 8};

int main() {
    int i;
    NODE m;
    m.i = 0;
    m.j = 9;
    pthread_t tid;

    int check;

    check = p_thread_create(&tid, NULL, mergesort, &m);

    if (check) {
        printf("Unable to create thread %d\n", check);
        exit(1);
    }

    pthread_join(tid, NULL);

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        printf("%d \n", x[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}

void merge(int i, int j) {
    int middle = (i+j)/2;
    int xi = i;
    int yi = middle+1;

    int newx[j-i+1], newxi = 0;

    while(xi <= middle && yi <= j) {
        if (x[xi] > x[yi]) {
            newx[newxi++] = x[yi++];
        }
        else {
            newx[newxi++] = x[xi++];
        }
    }

    while (xi <= middle) {
        newx[newxi++] = x[xi++];
    }

    while (yi <= j) {
        newx[newxi++] = x[yi++];
    }

    for (xi = 0; xi < (j-i+1); xi++) {
        x[i+xi] = newx[xi];
    }
}

void * mergesort(void *x) {
    NODE *p = (NODE *)x;
    NODE n1, n2;
    int middle = (p->i+p->j)/2;
    pthread_t tid1, tid2;
    int ret;

    n1.i = p->i;
    n1.j = middle;

    n2.i = middle+1;
    n2.j = p->j;

    if (p->i >= p->j) {
        return;
    }

    int check;

    check = pthread_create(&tid1, NULL, mergesort, &n1);

    if (check) {
        printf("Unable to create thread %d\n", check);
        exit(1);
    }

    check = pthread_create(&tid2, NULL, mergesort, &n2);

    if (check) {
        printf("Unable to create thread %d\n", check);
        exit(1);
    }

    p_thread_join(tid1, NULL);
    p_thread_join(tid2, NULL);

    merge(p->i, p->j);
    p_thread_exit(NULL);
}
```

What I have tried so far:

```
gcc -pthread thread.c
gcc thread.c -pthread
gcc -lpthread thread.c
gcc thread.c -lpthread
gcc -o thread thread.c -pthread
gcc -o thread thread.c -lpthread
gcc -pthread -o thread thread.c
gcc -lpthread -o thread thread.c
```

Comment: ohh.. I did not notice that. Thanks!

Comment: You will need to train yourself to see one-character mistakes like this.  But don't feel too bad about it; I have years and years of experience and I still miss them sometimes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three mistakes in this code:

1. All of the pthreads functions are named `pthread_something`, not `p_thread_something`.  The compiler will not correct this typo for you.  Remove the underscore after the 'p' everywhere it appears.
2. On at least some (BSD-derived?) systems, `stdlib.h` declares a function named `mergesort` with an incompatible signature, so you need to rename it.
3. You have a return statement with no value in the `mergesort` function, which is declared to return `void *`.  That needs to be changed to `return 0;`.

When I make those three changes your program works, or anyway it appears to work (it's supposed to print a sorted list of numbers, yes?)

Comment: I see I see, yupp it is supposed to print a sorted list of numbers. Thanks, I understand now!